# Renaming a tag (via merge) to an existing synonym does not work

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge-utility

On the Android site, [updates](/questions/tagged/updates) was a synonym of [update](/questions/tagged/update).  I wanted to reverse that, so I started a merge of [update](/questions/tagged/update) into [updates](/questions/tagged/updates).  With and without the synonym option checked, I got the generic "a problem has occurred" page.

On the tag synonyms page, there was an option to swap and merge these tags which worked fine.

Can we make it so that tag merging automatically does whatever it is the synonym page is doing when performing this kind of merge?